# clicking on select writes on page

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

I'm building a site and I'm using angular material.
I have a select tag with this code:

```
<md-select ng-model="year">
    <md-option><em></em></md-option>
    <md-option ng-repeat="n in [] | rangeYear" value="{{$index+startYear}}">
        {{$index+startYear}}
    </md-option>
</md-select>
```

'startYear' and 'year' are fields in the scope. The code for rangeYear:

```
app.filter('rangeYear', function () {
    return function (input) {
        var years = [];

        for (var i = 1924; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i += 1) {
            years.push(i);
        }
        return years;
    }
});
```

Each time I click on the select element (in the page), [[object HTMLElement]]
 is written in the top of the page.

does anyone know why does it happen? How can I prevent it?

EDIT:
I've uploaded the project to a server. This is thr link: http://rikudim.info/ang/

There is one dropdown list there.

Comment: Can you provide us with a working sample of your project?

Comment: It's not on a server, it's local

Comment: It's kinda hard to see why it writes this without something we can have a look at...

Comment: I have my project on github. Will it help?

Comment: Prefer to have it as a run ready code... It will save time for all others to help you find the problem.

Comment: @daan.desmedt the link: http://rikudim.info/ang/

Comment: Please fix `WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.` by removing your duplicate angularjs lib import. This could be a possible cause. Let me know when removed.

Comment: I changed the script source in the header from version 1.3.15 to 1.5.5 (like the version for the angular material) and it is fixed! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the warning is still there. I don't know which one to remove

Comment: Remove the double angular.js include script (line 5) - `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
`